# git post-review: command not found

Tags: git, review-board

when i tried to post review to main branch for my local commit , it says

`bash: post-review: command not found`

Command I tried is,

`$ post-review --parent mainbranch`

i am trying it from `git bash` windows. 
So Please tell me how to post review from git bash windows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`post-review` is an addon from [Reviewboard](https://www.reviewboard.org/), not part of git proper, and is included in [RBTools](https://github.com/reviewboard/rbtools).

Thus, this addon needs to be installed before the command is available. [Packaged releases are available for download directly from Reviewboard.](https://www.reviewboard.org/downloads/rbtools/#windows)

---

Note, however, that [as of this writing RBTools doesn't play well with the terminal emulator shipped with modern releases of git-bash](https://hellosplat.com/s/beanbag/tickets/4015/); thus, it may not work well for you.

Comment: I have not installed reviewboard addon. Let me try. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: you said it may not work well. So does that mean, "post-review" command itself useless ? is it a problem only in windows or unix as well ?

Comment: The issue applies to Windows only; can be avoided by using the built-in Windows terminal emulator rather than the (better) one provided by Git for Windows. I provided a link to the ticket; feel free to read it for more details.

Comment: read the link... They suggested to reinstall with windows console style.. do you think that will work ?

Comment: even after reinstalling it doesnot work. windows command prompt says `bash: post-review: command not found`

Comment: *shrug*. Bring it up with Reviewboard.

Comment: That said, you might find the location where installing RBTools put the git-post-review executable, and make sure it's in your PATH from git-bash. If it's not, adding a symlink or a shim might be appropriate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96173/discussion-between-logan-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: i tried setting path in windows my computer properties but it doesnt work. could you please let me know how to set git-post-review executable ?

Comment: can you pls help me here